# How to create a json_template?

Tags: java, android, geojson, osmbonuspack

I'm creating some code and I saw an example here on this forum, and I have a hard time using geojson.

Whenever it is giving an error in raw because I did not add this json_template

```
private String getGeoString() throws IOException{
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_template);
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    char[] buffer = new char [1024];
    try{
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        int n;
        while ((n= reader.read(buffer)) != -1){
            writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }finally {
        is.close();
    }
    String jsonString = writer.toString();
    return jsonString();
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: do you want to create a json in android ?

Comment: SO is not a forum, but Q&A site

Comment: Yes, I want to create a json file on android

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create a json file in your app, you can first create a `json_template.json` file in your *app* -> *res* -> *raw* folder.

In that file, you can put the entire json response received upon querying.

A useful tool to see the json traversal in the nested response is [JSON Pretty Print](http://jsonprettyprint.com/).

Then you can try:

```
public static String getGeoString(Context context) throws IOException {

   InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_template);
   Writer writer = new StringWriter();
   char[] buffer = new char[1024];

   try {
        Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        int n;
        while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
           writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
   } finally {
       is.close();
    }

 // The local variable 'jsonString' can be inlined as below
 return writer.toString(); 
}
```

It should work. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: the problem is that I can not add anything inside this json, because I want to add the markings I'm doing on the map. How would you add these points?

Comment: do you plan to add markings to a map, based on geojson data loaded from a raw resource file? If yes, are you familiar with Google Maps? you can have a look at the GeoJsonDemoActivity.java, in the demo app provided by Google Maps documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/geojson). It adds markings based on a local geojson file. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: it is not that I want to load the markings from within the geojson file, I want to create markings on my map and save them within geojson, for example: I clicked the screen at a certain point and gave a coordinate of that type, -5.013124, 13.0394958 , this coordinate has to be saved within a geojson, and just remembering that I use open street map